# Getting previous element in for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

**EDIT 2 (to make the problem more understandable)**

The effect I am trying to achieve is the following: everytime an element enters the viewport an 'is-visible' class is added to it and the same 'is-visible' class is removed from the previous element.

Now I've managed to make it work but I run a `for` loop to remove all `is-visible` classes before adding the `is-visible` class to the element in viewport.

It works but in terms of performance I think it would be better to just remove the class from `element[i -1]`. And this were I can't get it working.

Here is a simplified fiddle were I try to make the `element[i-1]` solution work: https://jsfiddle.net/epigeyre/vm36fpuo/11/.

---

**EDIT 1 (to answer some of the questions asked)**

I have corrected an issue raised by @Catalin Iancu (thanks a lot for your precious help) by using a modulus operator (`(i+len-1)%len`).

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION (not really clear)**

I am trying to get the previous element in a `for` loop (to change its class) with following code :

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(array[i-1] && my other conditions) {
        array[i-1].classList.remove('is-visible');
        array[i].classList.add('is-visible');
    }
}
```

But it's not removing the class for `[i-1]` element.

Here is a more complete piece of code of my module (this is running within a `scroll` eventlistener):

```
var services = document.getElementsByClassName('services'),
    contRect = servicesContainer.getBoundingClientRect();

for (var i = 0; i < services.length; i++) {
    var serviceRect = services[i].getBoundingClientRect();

    if ( !services[i].classList.contains('active') && Math.round(serviceRect.left) < contRect.right && services[i-1]) {
        services[i-1].classList.remove('is-visible');
        services[i].classList.add('is-visible');
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Um, no, it only gets the previous one. But since it is in a for loop, it will get the previous one for each iteration.

Comment: This sentence doesnt make sense `But it seems that [i-1] is getting all previous elements instead of just the previous one.` - that really does only read the previous instance from an array. PLease provide a [mcve] to demonstrate your exact problem.

Comment: In the first iteration i is 0... sooo you get all elements probably because you refer to the 0-1 = -1 array element... or you need to get an error for this.

Comment: how did you think that " [i-1] is getting all previous elements instead of just the previous one"? what happens ?

Comment: @FastSnail ohh yeah, true at the end of the line :)

Comment: @S.Serp I've udpated my question. Sorry I should have started with the real problem.

Comment: Are you sure its not one of the other conditions in your `if` clause stopping the class being removed when you think it should be? Try stepping through your code.

Comment: I have added a jsfiddle in my question, might be easier.

Answer (score 1):

Your `if(array[i-1] && my other conditions)` is always true, except for the very first case where `array[-1]` doesn't exist. Therefore, it will remove and then add the `active` class for each element, which will make it seem as only the first element's class has been removed.

What you need is a better `if` condition or a `break` statement, when the loop is not needed anymore

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(array[i] && i != array.length - 1) {
        array[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
}
array[array.length - 1].classList.add('active');
```

Comment: So it means that `if(array[i-1])` is not enought to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Yes, since `if (variable)` only verifies if that variable is different from `undefined` or other equivalent values, like 0, "", etc. Since your elements exist, it will always verify as true.

Comment: No, since your array elements are DOM objects, whose class is `services`. They do not evaluate to simple values like 0 or -1. I have edited my answer to contain a more probable solution to exactly what you want.

Comment: Sorry my previous comment was really stupid (my brain needs some time off). I have found another solution using modulos to prevent thos situation from happening. However this doesn't solve my issue. I've posted a jsfiddle in the question if it helps.

Comment: I see, it's related to the scroll. So, you want only the current top element from the screen visible, or something like that?

Comment: What I want is the element to get the class 'is-visible' (or whatever name) when it is in viewport (that's not too hard) and to remove this class when it's not anymore (this is the hard part for me).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155443/discussion-between-catalin-iancu-and-pipo).

Comment: Thanks again for your great help! I realized this morning, with a fresh mind that, event though your solution works great, it doesn't really answer my original question. It is important for me to understand how I could remove the class from the previous element when element enters viewport. I've edited my question accrodingly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably is that based on your code: `services[i-1].classList.remove('active');` and `services[i].classList.add('active');` the 'active' class you add in current iteration will be removed in next iteration!

So your code has logical errors, array index does not return all prev items!

Comment: Yes but that's what I want, everytime the conditions are met, the previous active class has to be removed. Am I not thinking this right?

Answer (score 0):

What if you create a variable that contain the previous element?

```
var previous = array[0];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(previous && my other conditions) {
        previous.classList.remove('active');
        array[i].classList.add('active');
    break;
    }
    previous = array[i];
}
```

Comment: I've tried that too... I've posted a jsfiddle in the question if you feel like having a look :)